# Replace M with MB in perl

Tags: perl, filesize

I have a perl script that shows the total storage of linux machine.

e.g  print $total_storage

And the output is 28G,477M

I want the output to come out as: 28GB,477MB.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Without more detail what you're doing and your input and output:

```
my $line = "28G,477M";

$line =~ s/([TGMk])/$1B/g;
print $line;
```